# React-Native image seems to load but it shows blank

Tags: javascript, react-native, amazon-s3

I'm using an S3 bucket as origin for my app's images. Storage.get seems to be working fine, as when I copy and paste the link on the browser, it loads the image correctly. However, the Image tag seems not to be working...

It seems to load the image correctly, as it shows its space in the app, but it doesn't show the actual image.

Here is the code:

```
  render() {
        return(
            <View style={Styles.vContainerF}>
                { this.state.gmpLogoURL ? 
                    <Image  style={{flex:1}}
                            resizeMode='contain'
                            source={{uri: this.state.gmpLogoURL }}
                     /> 
                : null }
```

This is the view style config:

```
  vContainerF: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 10,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
```

Any hints on what could be the issue?

Thanks in advance folks!

Comment: Did you try to print the url and see if it is correct?

Comment: try to add image height and width to your image styles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described in [react-native image doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image) :

> Note that for network and data images, you will need to manually specify the dimensions of your image!

So add `height` and `width` to your image style :

```js
<Image 
  style={{ flex: 1, height: 100, width: 100 }}
  resizeMode='contain'
  source={{ uri: this.state.gmpLogoURL }}
/>
```

Comment: Great, tks Kishan!